# Multiple loop to create a list of combinations

Tags: r, loops, combinations

I tried to use a loop to create a list of combinations, but I 'm not getting all the iterations and it's generating a smaller number than I expected.
The code that I'm using:

```
base = "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/r"
    codes = list(304020060, 304050083, 304010308, 304070017, 304010081, 304020184, 304050040, 304040045, 304010308, 304030074, 304020338, 304020079, 304040134, 304010081)      #14 different codes 
    month = c("01", "02", "03", "04","05","06","07","08", "09", "10", "11","12")
    year = c(2015:2018)


  for (i in base) {
    for(j in codes){
      for (k in month) {
        for (l in year) {
          html <-  paste(i, j, k, l, sep = "/" )
    }}}}
```

I was expecting to get one record for code, month and year (around 670 different records), but I'm only getting 14:

```
 [1] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304020060/12/2015"
 [2] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304050083/12/2016"
 [3] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304010308/12/2017"
 [4] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304070017/12/2018"
 [5] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304010081/12/2015"
 [6] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304020184/12/2016"
 [7] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304050040/12/2017"
 [8] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304040045/12/2018"
 [9] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304010308/12/2015"
[10] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304030074/12/2016"
[11] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304020338/12/2017"
[12] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304020079/12/2018"
[13] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304040134/12/2015"
[14] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/app/sec/304010081/12/2016"
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible (it is almost reproducible but `codes` is missing). Also consider to create a _minimal_ example. I am sure there is no need to post 14 different codes, 12 months ... to get the big picture.

Comment: You're only getting one month - `"12"` - in your output. Are you sure your `month` vector is what you think it is? Also, it might be handy to look at something like `?expand.grid` to make all your combinations without using multiple `for` loops.

Comment: Try `apply(expand.grid(base, codes, month, year), 1, paste, collapse = "/")`

Comment: I may be mistaken but how are you even getting multiple values? Are you not overwriting html with each iteration, not adding to it?

Comment: Markus, I'm trying to use this loop to collect data from this website. The codes are the 'disease' code that I need to look more closely through the years

Comment: @DiceboyT - Good idea - you could also refactor that to `do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(base, codes, month, year),sep="/"))` so that `paste` is only called once instead of for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to create a list of html strings from your vectors. This can be done quite simply.

From base, we can create a matrix with all combinations using the function `expand.grid`

```
combs <- expand.grid(base, codes, month, year)
```

following this we could create each string using an apply function applying over the first margin (`MARGIN = 1` is the same as iterating over rows of a matrix). For each row we want to perform the same paste as your

```
html <- apply(combs, 
              MARGIN = 1, 
              FUN = function(x)paste(x, collapse = "/"))
```

And your done. Basically the apply function takes the place of the loop. Notice that i've replace the `sep = "/"` argument of paste with a `collapse = "/"` argument. This is due to the fact that i am pasting a vector (each row in `combs`). Thus i am collapsing the matrix, not removing separation.

Answer (score 3):

You can speed your code up using `do.call`

```
out <- do.call(paste, c(base, expand.grid(codes, month, year), sep = "/"))
head(out)
#[1] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/r/304020060/01/2015"
#[2] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/r/304050083/01/2015"
#[3] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/r/304010308/01/2015"
#[4] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/r/304070017/01/2015"
#[5] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/r/304010081/01/2015"
#[6] "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/r/304020184/01/2015"
```

Check the number of elements

```
length(out)
#[1] 672
```

Since `base` is a constant there is no need to put it in `expand.grid`

Answer (score 2):

This works just fine, remember to save each iteration and not overwrite it.

```
base = "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/r"
    codes = list(304020060, 304050083, 304010308, 304070017, 304010081, 304020184, 304050040, 304040045, 304010308, 304030074, 304020338, 304020079, 304040134, 304010081)      #14 different codes 
    month = c("01", "02", "03", "04","05","06","07","08", "09", "10", "11","12")
    year = c(2015:2018)
    html=list()
    iteration=1


  for (i in base) {
    for(j in codes){
      for (k in month) {
        for (l in year) {
          html[[iteration]] <-  paste(i, j, k, l, sep = "/" )
          iteration<-iteration+1

    }}}}

 > length(html)
[1] 672
```

Comment: @AngélicaCarreira No problem, this works but some of the other answers are more suitable for efficiency and simplicity, check those and see if they work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing indices in `html <- paste(...)`. The way you have it, each iteration overwrites the previous `html`.

However, this would be clearer if you create a `data.frame` or `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
Base = "http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br/r"
Code = c(304020060, 304050083, 304010308, 304070017, 304010081, 304020184,
          304050040, 304040045, 304010308, 304030074, 304020338, 304020079,
          304040134, 304010081)
Mnth = c(paste0(0, 1:9), 10:12)
Year = c(2015:2018)
Combinations <- data.table(base = rep("http://sigtap.datasus.gov.br", times = 14 * 12 * 4),
                           code = rep(Code, each = 12 * 4),
                           month= rep(Mnth, each = 14 * 4),
                           year = rep(Year, each = 14 * 12))
Combinations[, URL := paste0(base, code, month, year)]
```

It's personal preference, but I try to avoid for loops unless extremely necessary. It is also good practice to not use the same name for objects and base functions. For example, `month` is a function that gets the month from a date. That's the reason I renamed `base`, `code`, `month` and `year`.

Comment: Hell Arturo, i'd suggest using `CJ(base, code, month, year)`. This will expand the vectors accordingly like `expand.grid` from the base package, while transforming your data into a data.table. As such `CJ(base = base, code = code, month = month, year = year)[, html = paste(base, code, month, year, sep = "/")]` will do the same job, but faster and more efficiently.

Comment: data.table i believe it might have to be in 2 lines however.